# With camel, how do I use the value of a header to define an XPath expression?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have a header which has an XPath definition in it:

```
myXPath = "/bookshop/author/books/1|/bookshop/author/books/2"
```

and I'd then like to use this in an Xpath expression to set another header something like this:

```
<setHeader headerName="authorBooks">
    <xpath resultType="org.w3c.dom.NodeList">${in.header.myXPath}</xpath>
</setHeader>
```

Reading the [docs](https://camel.apache.org/xpath.html) it seems you can use header values as part of your expression, but not to define the whole thing? I tried this and it didn't work:

```
<xpath resultType="org.w3c.dom.NodeList">in:header('myXPath')</xpath>
```

Anyone know of a way of doing this? I found this bug which seems to do what I want, but it's not slated to get fixed until 3.0:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-3697

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As almost always with Camel, when the DSL is limited for your situation, you can switch to doing this specific part in a plain Java processor/bean.

You can use the [XPathBuilder](https://camel.apache.org/xpath.html#XPath-UsingXPathBuilderwithoutanExchange) to execute your expression and manually retreive the header.

Psuedocode:

```
 String result = XPathBuilder.xpath(exchange.getIn().getHeader("myXpath",String.class)).evaluate(context, exchange.getIn().getBody());
```

Answer (score 1):

In Camel 2.11 this is easier as you can do xpath directly on headers. See [the official documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/xpath-language.html) at the section *Using XPath on Headers*.

Comment: OK, thanks Claus - I should have specified but I'm using 2.10; until 2.11 is officially released.